# C++ Problem with aggregate initialization for custom constructor in a struct

Tags: c++, struct, constructor

I'm trying to have a convenient way to declare variables of a structure and perform the initialization of some of its members in one line, like in the line

`optionValues option_showUnits {("No", "Yes", "Dynamic"), ("Yes")};`

I also need a custom constructor so that I can automatically obtain the array position in possible_values that matches the contents in default_value.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>


struct optionValues{
    const char* possible_values[3];
    char defaultValue[20];
    int value_index;
    
    // Constructor
    optionValues (const char *possible_values[], const char *defaultValue){
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            if(strcmp(possible_values[i], defaultValue) == 0){
                value_index = i;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
};

optionValues option_showUnits {("No", "Yes", "Dynamic"), ("Yes")};

int main() {
    // Access and print the array member
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        std::cout << option_showUnits.possible_values[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "value index is " << option_showUnits.value_index << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[These are the compilation error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbuN3.png)

However, when using a custom constructor, the code doesn't compile anymore. Apparently I'm not passing the right parameters and I don't know how to do it.

Comment: With a custom constructor, the struct is no longer an aggregate.

Comment: Also, the result of `("No", "Yes", "Dynamic")` is just `"Dynamic"`

Comment: C++ types like `std::vector` would allow `{"No", "Yes", "Dynamic"}` as a constructor parameter.  C style arrays do not for ancient reasons.

Comment: If you're doing C++ and you're ignoring `std::string` and instead force yourself to suffer through C strings, you're doing yourself a huge disservice. You may also want to consider an `enum` here than some arbitrary strings.

Comment: @tadman The reason I'm using C-strings is because I'm using Arduino ! Although it's for an ESP32, so by using the suggested more powerful C++ functions I may not have memory problems.

Comment: That's fine, but if you're under such constraints it's worth bringing that up in the question so we can frame our responses correctly. An `[arduino]` tag, or the ISA you're using, is often all it takes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a custom constructor, the `optionValues`  is not an aggregate and aggregate initialization can therefore not be done.

Also, this initialization

```cpp
optionValues option_showUnits {("No", "Yes", "Dynamic"), ("Yes")};
```

is equal to

```
optionValues option_showUnits {("Dynamic"), ("Yes")};
```

What you want is

```cpp
optionValues option_showUnits{{"No", "Yes", "Dynamic"}, {"Yes"}};
```

Then with a small adjustment to your constructor and making use of `std::array` instead of plain (C) arrays, you can make the initialization work:

```cpp
#include <array>

struct optionValues {
    std::array<const char*, 3> possible_values;
    std::array<char, 20> defaultValue;
    int value_index;

    // Constructor
    optionValues(std::array<const char*, 3> pv, std::array<char, 20> dv) :
        possible_values{pv}, defaultValue{dv} 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            if (strcmp(possible_values[i], defaultValue.data()) == 0) {
                value_index = i;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

```cpp
int main() {
    optionValues option_showUnits{{"No", "Yes", "Dynamic"}, {"Yes"}};

    // Access and print the array member
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        std::cout << option_showUnits.possible_values[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "value index is " << option_showUnits.value_index << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
No Yes Dynamic 
value index is 1
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9W3zocnxP)

---

- However, you should look into using `std::string` and `std::vector` instead. The `char*` pointers you store in the object are only valid for as long as the C strings you pass in to the constructor are still valid. With a slight modification, it would look like this:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstddef>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

struct optionValues {
    std::vector<std::string> possible_values;
    std::string defaultValue;
    std::size_t value_index;

    optionValues(std::vector<std::string> pv, const std::string& dv) :
        possible_values{std::move(pv)}, defaultValue{dv} 
    {
        if(auto it = std::find(possible_values.begin(), 
                               possible_values.end(),
                               defaultValue); it != possible_values.end()) 
        {
            value_index = std::distance(possible_values.begin(), it);
        }
    }
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/chsbT8MEW)

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate you providing two solutions.

Unfortunately, I failed to mention I was actually coding for an ESP32 using the Arduino framework.

Your [1st solution adapted for Arduino](https://codefile.io/f/wTyf2R8kgr) shows error: no matching function for call to 'optionValues::optionValues(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)

Your [2nd solution adapted for Arduino](https://codefile.io/f/s8ltV8eM2U) does work. "But dynamic memory is tricky on constrained platforms".

So I'd rather try and make the first approach work. Should I open a new question stating it's for Arduino?

Comment: The first verson _should_ work unless there's a bug in the `std::array` implementation or compiler itself. I guess making it `optionValues option_showUnits({"No", "Yes", "Dynamic"}, {"Yes"});` doesn't help? If it turns out it's a bug in the `std::array` implementation, just roll your own. [Here's a start](https://godbolt.org/z/aYoj1zec9)

Comment: Making that small change still makes the compiler show the same error.

https://ibb.co/wM5xt88

Comment: @AlejandroZ You haven't replaced `std::array` with `Array` like I showed in the example. In order to test if it works with an home made array, you need to actually replace `std::array` with `Array` everywhere.

Comment: Still the same result. With either {} or ()

https://ibb.co/kXw4PfN

Comment: @AlejandroZ That's annoying. What version is the compiler? [Here's another try](https://godbolt.org/z/qcG9Kfxc9)

Comment: This is the information I get when compiling with Vscode + Platformio:
 
- framework-arduinoespressif32 @ 3.20007.0 (2.0.7) 
 - tool-esptoolpy @ 1.40500.0 (4.5.0) 
 - toolchain-xtensa-esp32 @ 8.4.0+2021r2-patch5

That last try did compile without errors!

Comment: @AlejandroZ Ok, I thought the arduino compilers were  based on g++, but anyway, great that it worked out with the latest attempt :-)